# Alternate FTP source based on availability

Tags: ssis

I want to develop SSIS package in which I want to copy files from FTP location. This location will be configurable. I want that if FTP location is down due to any reason or not available then it will be able take files from some alternate FTP location. Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

## Precedence Constraint approach

Add an FTP task, Primary FTP, and then add a second FTP, Alt FTP. Connect the second to the first through a OnFailure constraint.

## Loop approach

Create an integer SSIS Variable, `FTPTryCount` assign it to zero.

Add a string Variable, `FTPConnectionString` with EvaluateAsExpression = true and use an expression like

```
(@[User::FTPTryCount] ==0)?"PrimaryFTPString":"AlternateFTPString"
```

If the value of FTPTryCount is zero, then we'll use the first connection string. Otherwise, we use the second string. Make those value connection strings for your system.

Configure the FTP Connection Manager to use the string from `@[User::FTPConnectionString]`

Add a boolean Variable `FileFound` and set it to false.

Add a For Loop. Terminal condition is `@[User::FTPTryCount] > 1 || @[User::FileFound]`

If we find the file or have tried twice, we want to exit the loop.

Inside your FTP Loop, you'll have an FTP Task and a Script Task. The Script Task will be in the OnSuccess path and all it does is set the FileFound to true.

## Script approach

Assuming the variables from the Loop approach exist, add a script task that will set the `@[User::FTPTryCount]` check the FTP Connection manager's connection string and then attempt to open a connection to it. Wrap it all in a try/catch block. If the connection opens, FTPTryCount remains 0. If the catch block fires, then you set it to 1.

From the Script Task, add your FTP task. Configure the FTP Connection Manager to use the string from `@[User::FTPConnectionString]`

### Error handling regardless of approach

The FTP task will fail if it can't connect to the remote server (or if no file is found). You'll need to handle this otherwise it's no good.

This is all high level, I have no access to an FTP site so you're on your own for physical implementation of the design but any of the above should work fine.